# How can i read data from External Oracle DB using Spring Batch?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a Spring boot + Spring Batch Application with External Source as : Oracle DB , Destination as : SQL Server in my Stage Server. I have a read user for oracle. I am getting the below error while reading the data from Source. Please find the below error logs.

Based on the error log, I added this property spring.batch.initializer.enabled=true 
but it still gives me same error.

Can you please advise how to fix it ?

```
ERROR [org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler] (pool-9-thread-1) Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:91)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:870)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:931)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:936)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.createJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:115)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:135)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.createJobExecution(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor48.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy90.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.elm.salamah.scheduler.batch.configuration.EmployeeBatchConfiguration.performThirdJob(EmployeeBatchConfiguration.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1044)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1329)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3665)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1352)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:877)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:870)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
    ... 45 more
```

Comment: _no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'_  => You don't have enough privileges to insert data to the `users` table. At least the account that you use to go to do the manipulation in the base can not do insert on this table.

Comment: @foxdie : The source is from External Client. I cannot ask them to provide access. I want to only read the data from Source. How can i avoid any insertion in the source DB ?

Comment: You try to do an `insert` have a look on the instruction you pass : _INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]_ except that the table "BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE" is in the tablespace of `USERS`. If you want to read only have look on your code to see where is this insert instruction.

Comment: I am not explicitly inserting record in BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE. Looks like it is a feature of Spring batch where it creates these metadata in both source and destination during run time. I want to restrict this feature. I tried this spring.batch.initializer.enabled=true  but it does not work in my stage server where source and destination DB are different. Any suggestion ?

Comment: I know, It's a shedule task there is two way `@Scheduled` annotation or in the XML configuration have a look on this [link](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks). That's why I say "have a look on your code to see where is this insert instruction".

Comment: Yes I understand. This is the code which is used to run the Job. JobExecution execution = (JobExecution) jobLauncher.run(importEmployeesJob(), param); and it is scheduled. But internally when the job is running, it is trying to insert data in tables. I am not sure how to restrict it as there is no privilege for read user.

Comment: Have you follow this [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureJob.html) to write your instruction?

Comment: Yes.. I have followed the official documentation. Things are perfectly working in Dev environment. But when it was deployed to stage, we were given read access to client DB. So I tried to execute spring batch jobs connecting to client DB but we are facing  this issue now.

Answer (score 1):

To manage the job run status and to have restart facility Spring batch  creates/uses these tables.

You can use `MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean` if you don’t want to persist these tables in database.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.html

sample java config for the same

```
@Bean
    public MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(ResourcelessTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(transactionManager);
        mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        return mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean;
    }



    @Bean
    public ResourcelessTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
    }
```

**Other Solution** 
 you can specify different datasource (for which you have insert access ) for creating  job repository .

Comment: Hi Niraj, Thanks for the update. I am using the method which you shared but this line was missing. mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager); . Anyway, I will try it and let you know.

Comment: Hi Niranj, Can you please let me know how can i check whether the tables have got created in in-memory DB ?

Comment: In-memory implementation is done using the collection API and not the in-memory DB . this is how JobInstance is defied in                         private final Map<String, JobInstance> jobInstances = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, JobInstance>();

Comment: if the provided solution helped you could you please accept the answer ?. This will also helps those  who have similar  issues :)

Comment: Hi Niraj.. I used your approach and in addition , I asked the client to provide tablespace for USERS. It looks be working fine now. Thanks for your support !

Comment: This is how you accept the answer  :)  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers